# GStreamer 1.0 1.4.5 RTSP Example Server sends 503 Service unavailable

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to make RTSP server based on Gstreamer 1.0 1.4.5 plugin. Source code of the example is taken from [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/examples/test-video.c). *WITH_TLS* and *WITH_AUTH* flags are **not** enabled.

I'm compiling it using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. The project is building and running successfully. However when I'm trying to play the video using VLC on address *rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test* it says it can't open the MRL.

Recorded traffic (using RawCap) of the communication between compiled server and VLC player is the following:

```
Request: 
OPTIONS rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test RTSP/1.0 
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.0 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)

Response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, GET_PARAMETER, PAUSE, PLAY, SETUP, SET_PARAMETER, TEARDOWN
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 03:35:30 GMT

Request:
DESCRIBE rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.2.0 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
Accept: application/sdp

Response:
RTSP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
CSeq: 3
Server: GStreamer RTSP server
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 03:35:30 GMT
```

The RTSP server have no errors or warnings in either IDE or command promt window.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding extra trace to the code to see where an error occurs? If it's 500 it's likely that one of these calls is failing and the code as it is wont point you towards this.

Comment: I set GST_DEBUG to warning level and now I see that I have no element `x264enc`. Now I'm trying to figure out how to add it in Windows.

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. It is not installed by MSI installer by default. Anyone wanting it needs to check "restricted codecs with potential patent issues in some countries" while installing GStreamer SDK.

Comment: Its in the ugly plugins package, so it would seem. Yep don't think that comes by default. Glad you fixed it. You could post it as an answer, even if you can't accept it, you may get upvotes on it from other people.